# Max value of a column using generics

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, generic-programming

I am working on a project.It's following "Unit of work" pattern.I want to write a Dynamic method where I will pass the table name it will return the max value of primary key column or I will pass the table and column name it will return the max value of that column. It will look something like this--

```
public int GetMaxPK<T>()
{
    GetMaxId= ??
    return GetMaxId;
}
```

Is it possible? How can I do this? Or any suggestion?

Comment: you could use the `where` constraint and specify an Interface or BaseType supporting such value: `public int GetMaxPK<T>() where T is BaseType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Project,I wrote in mvc controller to get maxId like this--

```
public class PurchaseOrderController : Controller
{    
   private IPurchaseOrder interfaceRepository;

    public PurchaseOrderController()
    {
        if (interfaceRepository==null)
        {
            this.interfaceRepository= new Repository();
        }
    }
    int maxId=interfaceRepository.GetMaxPK(a=>a.POMSTID);
}
```

here

> a=>a.POMSTID

is the colum selector that you want to query.Suppose you want to select column named "PODETID" then column selector will be like this--

> a=>a.PODETID

now in interface --

```
    public interface IPurchaseOrder:IRepository<PURCHASEORDERMASTER>
    {

    }
```

Here "PURCHASEORDERMASTER" is my query table or TEntity.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    int GetMaxPK(Func<TEntity, decimal> columnSelector);
}
```

now in the repository(or concrete) class(that inherit the interface) where you call the db you have to write like this--

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
 {   

    public int GetMaxPK(Func<TEntity, decimal> columnSelector)
    {
        var GetMaxId = db.Set<TEntity>().Max(columnSelector);
        return GetMaxId;
    }
 }
```

here db is the database context and decimal is the data type of my query column.

Comment: Excellent.your answer solved my problem.A lot of days i am trying to get maxID dynamically but could not find the solution.According to your answer  it gives me maxID perfectly.thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) with one properties:

```
public interface IMax
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then your generic class should implement this interface:

```
public class yourClass<T> where T : class , IMax
```

Finally:

```
public int GetMaxPK()
{
    GetMaxId= yourTable.Max(c => c.Id);
    return GetMaxId;
}
```

Your complete code should be something like this:

```
public class yourClass<T>  where T : class, IMax
{
    public int GetMaxPK(IEnumerable<T> yourTable)
    {
        var GetMaxId = yourTable.Max(c => c.Id);
        return GetMaxId;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using different name(as primary key column) for different table not using as "id".So i have to pass column name either or pick primary key column whatever name it has.

Comment: @MohammadSadiqurRahman When you are using the generic you should try to have more common logic as you can. So I'd suggest to rename your PK to ids or something that is same in all of your tables..

Comment: can i make my column name dynamic also?

Comment: @MohammadSadiqurRahman You can use `System.Linq.Dynamic` as I answered in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/44143131/2946329 However I still recommend to rename your PKs to something that is same in all of your tables which make your code more readable and reusable.

Comment: @MohammadSadiqurRahman You can also use reflection, which is very expensive in general terms and it doesn't recommended for this scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using something similar to the Max extension method

```
TResult Max<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

Which when adapted to your scenario

```
public int GetMaxPK<TTable>(IEnumerable<TTable> table, Func<TTable, int> columnSelector) {
    var maxId= table.Max(columnSelector);
    return maxId;
}
```

Or assuming the source is already internal to the encapsulating class for example something like `DbContext`

```
DbContext db;

//...

public int GetMaxPK<TTable>(Func<TTable, int> columnSelector) {
    var maxId = db.Set<TTable>().Max(columnSelector);
    return maxId;
}
```

And called like

```
var maxId = myClass.GetMaxPK<TableName>(t => t.PKColumnName);
```